# How to validate a password in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords

This is the code I wrote, it returns the alert every time even if the password is within the range(4-12).

```
function PasswordCheck() {
  var str = document.getElementById("Password");
  if (str > 4 && str < 12) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("invalid password, your password needs to have 4-12 letters");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Does it not work as you expect? Please give more details.

Comment: The mistake is here: `if (str > 4 && str < 12)` – change it to `if (str.length > 4 && str.length < 12)`. You want to check the length of the string, not the string

Comment: `var field = document.getElementById("Password"), val = field.value, len = val.length; if (len > 4 && len < 12) return true; ...`

Comment: @PatrickHund you mean `str.value.length`

Comment: If you guys have an answer, please set as answer instead of comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the text in your element with  `value`.

Then you want to check the length of your string with the  `length` property of the `str` string.

```
function PasswordCheck() {
  var str = document.getElementById("Password").value;
  if (str.length > 4 && str.length < 12) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("invalid password, your password needs to have 4-12 letters");
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

This is because [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object and not the value directly.